# How to setup proper tracking for a Amazon Site?

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

So I have an Amazon Site with lots of elements like tables, sites for a single product and so on.

Here is what I want to archieve: I want to track the CTR for every single page particular.

So in the end here is what I want to be able to archieve:
Site xyz: 39% CTR to Amazon, then you can get more detailed stats for this site for example : Button 1 ( that is on Site xyz) got a 17% CTR and Button 2(that is also on Site xyz) got a 22% CTR.

So what would be the best way to archieve this ? Event Tracking I guess?
For example?
onclick="ga('send','event','Page xyz','click','Button whatever?');"

Really need some help on this :( And no I can not use a link shortener or whatever for this because I do not want to cloak the Amazon Links.

Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0):

Your English is much better than any second language I can speak, so no need to apologize.

I don't know that I have a complete understanding about your setup and what you want to achieve, but I have a couple of suggestions that will probably be part of the solution.

The first is that you'll have to add GA events to your outbound links. I suggest using a library like [Google Analytics on Steroids](https://github.com/CardinalPath/gas).

This will enable you to track all the links on your site that go to products on amazon.com. It will also track all other outbound links as a bonus.

Next, you'll want to use [enhanced link attribution](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2558867?hl=en) to see which buttons on a page perform better.